# Why doesn't the new marker show up when I click on the map?

Tags: flutter, google-chrome, google-maps, google-maps-markers

When I click on the map, the addMarker function receives the LatLng point and updates the _markers property correctly (which I can tell from the print(_markers.first.position.latitude) statement, but the map on the web page continues to show the old marker and does not update to show the newly created marker. If I save the page, close, and then open it, the new marker location shows up properly. I have run the code on Chrome and Edge browsers and get the same issue. What am I doing wrong?

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_web_app_3/data/model/tour_stop.dart';
import 'package:flutter_web_app_3/screens/tour_editor/models/place.dart';
import 'package:flutter_web_app_3/screens/tour_editor/services/geoLocation_service.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class LocationSelector extends StatefulWidget {
  // TourStop tourStop;
  final TourStop tourStop;
  const LocationSelector({super.key, required this.tourStop});

  @override
  State<LocationSelector> createState() => _LocationSelectorState();
}

class _LocationSelectorState extends State<LocationSelector> {
  final Completer<GoogleMapController> _mapController = Completer();
  StreamSubscription? locationSubscription;
  final _locationController = TextEditingController();
  Set<Marker> _markers = {};
  GeoPoint? _initLoc;
  MapType _currentMapType = MapType.normal;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    final locationServicesBloc =
        Provider.of<GeoLocationService>(context, listen: false);

    Future<void> initializeMap(LatLng? position) async {
      if (position != null) {
        final initMarker = Marker(
          markerId: MarkerId(widget.tourStop.title as String),
          position: position,
        );
        setState(() {
          _markers = <Marker>{initMarker};
        });
        final GoogleMapController controller = await _mapController.future;
        controller.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newLatLngZoom(position, 18));
      }
    }

    // Check if the tourStop has a legimate location already and initialize the map to that location
    if (widget.tourStop.tourStopGeo != null &&
        (widget.tourStop.tourStopGeo?.latitude != 0.0 ||
            widget.tourStop.tourStopGeo?.longitude != 0.0)) {
      _initLoc = widget.tourStop.tourStopGeo;
      initializeMap(LatLng(_initLoc!.latitude, _initLoc!.longitude));
    } else {
      _markers = <Marker>{}; // Set _markers to an empty set
      final currentLocation = locationServicesBloc.currentLocation;
      setState(() {
        _initLoc =
            GeoPoint(currentLocation!.latitude, currentLocation.longitude);
      });
    }
    locationSubscription =
        locationServicesBloc.selectedLocation.stream.asBroadcastStream().listen(
              (place) {
                if (place != null) {
                  _locationController.text = place.name!;
                  _goToPlace(place);
                } else {
                  _locationController.text = "";
                }
              },
              onError: (err) {
                print(err);
              },
              cancelOnError: false,
              onDone: () {
                print('done');
              },
            );

    locationServicesBloc.bounds.stream
        .asBroadcastStream()
        .listen((bounds) async {
      final GoogleMapController controller = await _mapController.future;
      controller.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newLatLngBounds(bounds!, 50));
    });
  }

  void addMarker(LatLng point) {
    setState(() {
      final newMarker = Marker(
        markerId: MarkerId(widget.tourStop.title as String),
        position: point,
      );
      _markers.clear(); // Clear the _markers set before adding the new marker
      _markers = <Marker>{newMarker};
    });
    print(point);
    print(_markers.first.position.latitude);
  }

  void _toggleMapType() {
    setState(() {
      _currentMapType = _currentMapType == MapType.normal
          ? MapType.satellite
          : MapType.normal;
    });
  }

  handleSubmit() async {
    final geoPoint = GeoPoint(
      _markers.first.position.latitude,
      _markers.first.position.longitude,
    );
    // BlocProvider.of<TourEditorBloc>(context)
    //     .add(UpdateTourStopLocation(tourStopGeo: geoPoint));
    // BlocProvider.of<TourEditorBloc>(context).add(ReturnFromMapEditor());
    // Navigator.pop(context);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final locationServicesBloc = Provider.of<GeoLocationService>(context);

    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButtonLocation:
          FloatingActionButtonLocation.miniCenterFloat,
      // floatingActionButton: _markers.isNotEmpty
      //     ? FloatingActionButton(
      //         child: const Icon(Icons.remove),
      //         onPressed: () {
      //           setState(() {
      //             _markers.clear();
      //           });
      //         },
      //       )
      //     : null,
      appBar: AppBar(
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        title: const Text('Tour Stop Location'),
        actions: [
          TextButton(
            child: const Text(
              'CANCEL',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              // BlocProvider.of<TourEditorBloc>(context)
              //     .add(ReturnFromMapEditor());
              Navigator.pop(context, _markers.first.position);
            },
          ),
          TextButton(
            onPressed: _markers != null
                ? () {
                    handleSubmit();
                    Navigator.pop(context, _markers.first.position);
                  }
                : null,
            child: Text(
              'SAVE CHANGES',
              style: _markers != null
                  ? const TextStyle(color: Colors.white)
                  : TextStyle(color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.2)),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),

      //wait for current location in order to use it in the GoogleMap below
      body: (locationServicesBloc.currentLocation == null)
          ? const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
          : Stack(
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  child: GoogleMap(
                    onTap: (point) => addMarker(point),
                    markers: _markers,
                    mapType: _currentMapType,
                    myLocationButtonEnabled: true,
                    myLocationEnabled: true,
                    initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                      target: LatLng(
                        _initLoc != null
                            ? _initLoc!.latitude
                            : locationServicesBloc.currentLocation!.latitude,
                        _initLoc != null
                            ? _initLoc!.longitude
                            : locationServicesBloc.currentLocation!.longitude,
                      ),
                      zoom: 18,
                    ),
                    onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
                      _mapController.complete(controller);
                    },
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(58.0),
                  child: TextField(
                    onChanged: (value) =>
                        locationServicesBloc.searchPlaces(value),
                    onTap: () => locationServicesBloc.clearSelectedLocation(),
                    autofocus: false,
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
                      filled: true,
                      fillColor: Colors.white,
                      hintText: 'Location',
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                if (locationServicesBloc.searchResults != null &&
                    locationServicesBloc.searchResults!.isNotEmpty)
                  Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 57, 10, 0),
                    width: double.infinity,
                    height: 400,
                    decoration:
                        BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.7)),
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: locationServicesBloc.searchResults!.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return ListTile(
                          onTap: () {
                            locationServicesBloc.setSelectedLocation(
                              locationServicesBloc
                                  .searchResults![index]!.place_id as String,
                            );
                            FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
                          },
                          title: Text(
                            locationServicesBloc
                                .searchResults![index]!.description as String,
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                FloatingActionButton(
                  onPressed: _toggleMapType,
                  tooltip: 'Toggle Map Type',
                  child: const Icon(Icons.map),
                )
              ],
            ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> _goToPlace(Place place) async {
    final GoogleMapController controller = await _mapController.future;
    controller.animateCamera(
      CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(
        CameraPosition(
          target: LatLng(
            place.geometry!.location!.lat as double,
            place.geometry!.location!.lng as double,
          ),
          zoom: 18.0,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    final locationServicesBloc =
        Provider.of<GeoLocationService>(context, listen: false);
    _locationController.dispose();
    locationSubscription?.cancel();
    locationServicesBloc.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appears to have been the markerId was not changing to something unique each time I clicked the map. To solve this, I changed the addMarker function to the following, which solved the problem:

```
void addMarker(LatLng point) {
final newMarker = Marker(
  markerId: MarkerId(DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString()),
  position: point,
);
setState(() {
  _markers = <Marker>{newMarker};
});
```

}